# padding Soft input resize adjust in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, window-soft-input-mode

I'm Trying to resize my screen on xamarin android when soft input appears.
but my problem is i want to set padding for my view in resize mode.
for example i want my view has 10 padding from top when soft input appears. but it fill my screen.
I'm using this code after by loadApplication method

```
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>()
            .UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Answer (score 0):

no event trigged while you have changed the `softInputMethod`. but there is a workaround like this to handle global layout changes

```cs
            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            mChildOfContent = content.GetChildAt(0);
            ViewTreeObserver vto = mChildOfContent.ViewTreeObserver;
            vto.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            //do whatever you want!
            //possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
            };
```